# Are "I am touched by the film" and "I am moved by the film" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to my study, "**I am moved by the film**" sounds like I am sad and cry when I feel sorry for the the characters in the film

"**I am touched by the film**" is similar but a bit weaker emotion.

Because "**touched**" is just a contact that does not make something move. However, "**moved**" is a strong contact that makes something move.

That is what I think, but I might get it wrong.

Are "**I am moved by the film**" and "**I am touched by the film**" similar but the former is stronger than the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several dictionaries give *moved* as a synonym of *touched*!

We generally use *touched* to refer to gratitude for an unexpected kindness, but it can also refer to feelings of sympathy with another person's plight.

In general, you are correct in saying that a *moving* film elicits stronger emotions than a *touching* one.